# select element with class="{c}"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the element with `class="{c}"`

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
</div>
```

here is my jQuery code :

```
$('#main').find('.{c}' ).each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).html());
})
```

but i get error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .{c}
```

how can i select this element ?

**btw , I'm scraping data from some website using chrome puppeteer ... i don't own the website and can't change the class name**

Comment: `{` and `}` are not valid characters for classes - can you change your html?

Comment: @chazsolo no , im scraping data from some website

Comment: use \ escape, '.\{c\}', try it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape the curly braces using two backslashes:

```
$(".\\{c\\}")
```

[As per the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

So using your example:

```
$('#main').find('.\\{c\\}' ).each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).html());
})
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/83tcg7fb/

Comment: thanx , i actually thought of that but tried one backslash

Answer (score 2):

Despite `{` and `}` being invalid characters for classes, you can use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (specifically `^=` for prefix) considering you can't change the HTML

```js
$('#main').find('[class^="{c"]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="{c}"> some data </div>
  <div class="{c}"> some data </div>
  <div class="{c}"> some data </div>
  <div class="{c}"> some data </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.escapeSelector( "{c}" )`

```
$('#main').find( "." + $.escapeSelector( "{c}" ) ).each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).html());
})
```

```js
$('#main').find( "." + $.escapeSelector( "{c}" ) ).each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use contains selector **(*)**

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```js
$('#main').children('div[class*=c]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
})
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

 <div id="main">
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
    <div class="{c}">  some data </div>
</div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/arzBYm